# Ordering a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Say if I had a list of lists like `[[1,3,4],[1,5,6,7],[2,8,0]]` or `["QQQ", "RRRR", "TTTTT"]` , is there a function that will order them by the number of elements in inner lists i.e. so in the `Int` list, the 4 element list goes to the front and in the `String`s list, the `T`s go to the front and then the `R`s?

Comment: so, [sortBy](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Data-List.html#v:sortBy)?

Answer (score 6):

Use [sortBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3asortBy) with a custom predicate:

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> let l = [[1,3,4],[1,5,6,7],[2,8,0]]
Prelude Data.List> sortBy (\e1 e2 -> compare (length e2) (length e1))  l
[[1,5,6,7],[1,3,4],[2,8,0]]
```

**Edit**: Thanks @JJJ for a more beautiful variant

```
Prelude Data.List> import Data.Ord
Prelude Data.List Data.Ord> sortBy (flip $ comparing length) l
[[1,5,6,7],[1,3,4],[2,8,0]]
```

Comment: `\e1 e2 -> compare (length e2) (length e1)` == `flip $ comparing length`.

Comment: You can make your sortBy comparator cleaner by importing `Data.ord.comparing`. Then you can write `sortBy (comparing length) l`

Comment: I was actually thinking more of `comparing` than `compare`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`sortBy` from Data.List and `comparing` from Data.Ord will help you.

```
foo = sortBy (comparing (negate . length))

bar = foo ["QQQ", "RRRR", "TTTTT"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add another solution that memoizes the lengths of given lists. Otherwise the lengths are recomputed with each comparison, which will mean a lot of overhead for large lists.

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.List (sort, sortBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

sortByLen :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
sortByLen = map snd . sortBy (comparing fst) . map ((negate . length) &&& id)
```

If you also want that lists of the same length get sorted lexicographically, you can use slightly simpler

```
sortByLen' :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
sortByLen' = map snd . sort . map ((negate . length) &&& id)
```